# Filtering list of tuples with isPrefixOf

Tags: haskell

I am in need of a function, which can do the following:

```
prefixes :: String -> [String] -> [(Int,String)]
prefixes "apples" ["ap","appl","le"] == [(0, "ap"), (1, "appl")] :: [(Int, String)]
```

So far I have managed to make this:

```
prefixes xs (y:ys) = filter ((isPrefixOf xs).snd) a where
a=(zip [0..] (y:ys))
```

But the result of this is an empty list, and I can not figure out a way to make it work.
(Yes, this was a homework, which I failed to complete on time, but I am still curious about the way to do it properly)

Comment: You're almost there. Try `prefixes x xs = filter ((`isPrefixOf` x) . snd) $ zip [0..] xs`. The only change is the usage of `isPrefixOf`, which according to the documentation 'takes two lists and returns True iff the **first** list is a prefix of the **second**.' (so you did it the other way around).                                                     Enclosing a function in backquotes makes it infix, in case you were wondering.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The naming of `isPrefixOf` can be slightly confusing at times, as it's intended to be used infix with backticks, e.g.

```
> "ap" `isPrefixOf` "apples"
True
```

However, this means that when we write it without the backticks, the argument order is

```
isPrefixOf "ap" "apples"
```

so the partial application `isPrefixOf xs` is the function that checks if `xs` is a prefix of its argument, not the other way round. This is why you get an empty list, as you're checking if `"apples"` is a prefix of any of the shorter strings, which obviously returns `False` for all of them.

There are three simple ways of fixing this. One is to use `flip`, which swaps the order of the arguments for a two-parameter function:

```
flip isPrefixOf xs
```

The second is to use backticks in an operator section:

```
(`isPrefixOf` xs)
```

The third is to be explicit and use a lambda:

```
\y -> y `isPrefixOf` xs
```